# Python multiprocessing TypeError

Tags: python, pandas

I have some code like this.

I am getting an error when I do jobs[i].get() which is a  multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object

**`TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable`**

```
import multiprocessing 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def tf(x):
    return np.mean(x)

def main():
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(6)
    sds=pd.Series(np.random.normal(0,.01,1000))
    jobs=[]

    for i in xrange(10):
        jobs.append(pool.apply_async(pd.rolling_apply(sds,2,tf)))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()


    for i in xrange(len(jobs)):
        jobs[i].get()




if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: not related to the question: replace your last loop with `for job in jobs: job.get()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

is because you pass **the result of the function** to pool, not the **function itself**, as you should have to do.

You should do as follows:

```
import multiprocessing 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def tf(x):
    return np.mean(x)

def main():
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(6)
    sds=pd.Series(np.random.normal(0,.01,1000))
    jobs=[]

    for i in xrange(10):
        jobs.append( pool.apply_async(pd.rolling_apply, (sds,2,tf)) )

    pool.close()
    pool.join()


    for i in xrange(len(jobs)):
        jobs[i].get()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
0          NaN
1     0.009682
2     0.002747
3     0.005108
4     0.002115
5     0.000449
6     0.011551
7     0.000686
8    -0.004860
9    -0.007568
10   -0.005052
11   -0.004860
12   -0.003354
13    0.005291
14    0.000845
...
985   -0.001762
986   -0.008001
987   -0.007872
988   -0.007356
989   -0.003436
990   -0.003725
991   -0.010541
992   -0.001246
993    0.002308
994    0.004322
995    0.010862
996    0.003545
997   -0.002039
998    0.003992
999   -0.006216
Length: 1000, dtype: float64
0          NaN
1     0.009682
2     0.002747
3     0.005108
4     0.002115
5     0.000449
6     0.011551
7     0.000686
8    -0.004860
9    -0.007568
10   -0.005052
11   -0.004860
12   -0.003354
13    0.005291
14    0.000845
...
985   -0.001762
986   -0.008001
987   -0.007872
988   -0.007356
989   -0.003436
990   -0.003725
991   -0.010541
992   -0.001246
993    0.002308
994    0.004322
995    0.010862
996    0.003545
997   -0.002039
998    0.003992
999   -0.006216
Length: 1000, dtype: float64
0          NaN
1     0.009682
2     0.002747
3     0.005108
4     0.002115
5     0.000449
6     0.011551
7     0.000686
8    -0.004860
9    -0.007568
10   -0.005052
11   -0.004860
12   -0.003354
13    0.005291
14    0.000845
...
985   -0.001762
986   -0.008001
987   -0.007872
988   -0.007356
989   -0.003436
990   -0.003725
991   -0.010541
992   -0.001246
993    0.002308
994    0.004322
995    0.010862
996    0.003545
997   -0.002039
998    0.003992
999   -0.006216
Length: 1000, dtype: float64
0          NaN
1     0.009682
2     0.002747
3     0.005108
4     0.002115
5     0.000449
6     0.011551
7     0.000686
8    -0.004860
9    -0.007568
10   -0.005052
11   -0.004860
12   -0.003354
13    0.005291
14    0.000845
...
985   -0.001762
986   -0.008001
987   -0.007872
988   -0.007356
989   -0.003436
990   -0.003725
991   -0.010541
992   -0.001246
993    0.002308
994    0.004322
995    0.010862
996    0.003545
997   -0.002039
998    0.003992
999   -0.006216
Length: 1000, dtype: float64
0          NaN
1     0.009682
2     0.002747
3     0.005108
4     0.002115
5     0.000449
6     0.011551
7     0.000686
8    -0.004860
9    -0.007568
10   -0.005052
11   -0.004860
12   -0.003354
13    0.005291
14    0.000845
...
985   -0.001762
986   -0.008001
987   -0.007872
988   -0.007356
989   -0.003436
990   -0.003725
991   -0.010541
992   -0.001246
993    0.002308
994    0.004322
995    0.010862
996    0.003545
997   -0.002039
998    0.003992
999   -0.006216
Length: 1000, dtype: float64
0          NaN
1     0.009682
2     0.002747
3     0.005108
4     0.002115
5     0.000449
6     0.011551
7     0.000686
8    -0.004860
9    -0.007568
10   -0.005052
11   -0.004860
12   -0.003354
13    0.005291
14    0.000845
...
985   -0.001762
986   -0.008001
987   -0.007872
988   -0.007356
989   -0.003436
990   -0.003725
991   -0.010541
992   -0.001246
993    0.002308
994    0.004322
995    0.010862
996    0.003545
997   -0.002039
998    0.003992
999   -0.006216
Length: 1000, dtype: float64
0          NaN
1     0.009682
2     0.002747
3     0.005108
4     0.002115
5     0.000449
6     0.011551
7     0.000686
8    -0.004860
9    -0.007568
10   -0.005052
11   -0.004860
12   -0.003354
13    0.005291
14    0.000845
...
985   -0.001762
986   -0.008001
987   -0.007872
988   -0.007356
989   -0.003436
990   -0.003725
991   -0.010541
992   -0.001246
993    0.002308
994    0.004322
995    0.010862
996    0.003545
997   -0.002039
998    0.003992
999   -0.006216
Length: 1000, dtype: float64
0          NaN
1     0.009682
2     0.002747
3     0.005108
4     0.002115
5     0.000449
6     0.011551
7     0.000686
8    -0.004860
9    -0.007568
10   -0.005052
11   -0.004860
12   -0.003354
13    0.005291
14    0.000845
...
985   -0.001762
986   -0.008001
987   -0.007872
988   -0.007356
989   -0.003436
990   -0.003725
991   -0.010541
992   -0.001246
993    0.002308
994    0.004322
995    0.010862
996    0.003545
997   -0.002039
998    0.003992
999   -0.006216
Length: 1000, dtype: float64
0          NaN
1     0.009682
2     0.002747
3     0.005108
4     0.002115
5     0.000449
6     0.011551
7     0.000686
8    -0.004860
9    -0.007568
10   -0.005052
11   -0.004860
12   -0.003354
13    0.005291
14    0.000845
...
985   -0.001762
986   -0.008001
987   -0.007872
988   -0.007356
989   -0.003436
990   -0.003725
991   -0.010541
992   -0.001246
993    0.002308
994    0.004322
995    0.010862
996    0.003545
997   -0.002039
998    0.003992
999   -0.006216
Length: 1000, dtype: float64
0          NaN
1     0.009682
2     0.002747
3     0.005108
4     0.002115
5     0.000449
6     0.011551
7     0.000686
8    -0.004860
9    -0.007568
10   -0.005052
11   -0.004860
12   -0.003354
13    0.005291
14    0.000845
...
985   -0.001762
986   -0.008001
987   -0.007872
988   -0.007356
989   -0.003436
990   -0.003725
991   -0.010541
992   -0.001246
993    0.002308
994    0.004322
995    0.010862
996    0.003545
997   -0.002039
998    0.003992
999   -0.006216
Length: 1000, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yes, it has:  `apply_async(func[, args[, kwds[, callback]]])`

Answer (score 1):

It's because the first argument of `pool.apply_async` should be a function but you are passing the result of `pd.rolling_apply` which is a `Series`. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve with this code but I think you might want something like this inside the loops

```
func = lambda s: pd.rolling_apply(s, 2, tf)
job = pool.apply_async(func, sds)
jobs.append(job)
```

Also, I you can just pass `np.mean` into `pd.rolling_apply` like

```
lambda s: pd.rolling_apply(s, 2 np.mean)
```

The definition of `tf` appears redundant to me.

Answer (score 0):

Apply async usage:
`apply_async(func[, args[, kwds[, callback]]])`

func is the callable, args are parameters. You have to pass 
`pd.rolling_apply` as function and `(sds,2,tf)` as arguments.

Simply:
`jobs.append(pool.apply_async(pd.rolling_apply, (sds,2,tf)))`

Be aware that for one argument only you have to pass additional comma:
`jobs.append(pool.apply_async(pd.rolling_apply, (sds,)))`